# Set 0 for input value when deleting all value

Tags: html

anybody know how to create a `textbox` that give a 0 `value` if I delete the `value`? For example, I have `textbox` which `value` is 0, then I type 10000 to it. then, if I delete all of it, it will return 0, not an empty `textbox`. it works like `placeholder` attribute, but I need its value, so I can't use `placeholder`

I'm using PHP, JS, JQ, and HTML for it.

Comment: Can you add your code? It will make it much easier for people to give you an answer.

Comment: Hello Jim, it's just a normal textbox... <input type="text" />

Comment: Something like: `var textbox = document.getElementByID('...'); var val = textbox.value || 0;`?

Comment: Do you mean something like placeholder attribute <input type="text" placeholder="0" />

Comment: I forgot where I can find feature like this. But it's not like that, it will return 0 if I delete all of the value in textbox

Comment: @Harsh, Yes! Something like placeholder but it's not a placeholder because I need its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found how to do it:

```
<input type="text" name="voucher" value="0" id="voucher" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value=0;}"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery for this, but if you need only php & html then use `placeholder`, something like this:

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="0" />
```

**php**

```
$value = $_POST['name']?0:$_POST['name'];
```

**using jQuery:**

```js
$('.not_empty').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == ""){
    $(this).val(0);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" class="not_empty" />
```

Comment: Helo Pepo, I don't need php and html only, maybe a jquery would be better than this code, because I will add this function to another function

Comment: i added short jQuery for you

Comment: Hello Pepo, it's not working. Already try run code snippet, still not working